# Save & Download a Json file in Unity WebGL

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, download, save, unity-webgl

I would like to create a system where a player/ user click on a **button**  to **save and download a Json** file listing the name and position of game objects in a **Unity WebGL** scene.
I am able to write the Json file with the required content in the editor. But I dont know How can I do it in WebGL. I was reading about **.jslb plugins**. But couldnt figure out how I can write one for my requirement.

Many thanks in Advance!
:)

Comment: Download from where? Save where? Sounds strange to first save and the download a file .. wouldn't it be the other way round?

Comment: Hi, 
Saving the gameobject name and positions to a Json file from the Webgl build and then download it to the local device. :)

Comment: You looked at e.g. [this plugin](https://github.com/nateonusapps/WebGLFileSaverForUnity)? Currently your question is too broad .. try to solve one problem at a time .. are you asking how to create a JSON file or are you asking how to store a file from WebGL to the local device? ;)

Comment: Thank you for the Plugin link! Shall go through it. I managed to create a Json with the necessary game data. 
`saveContent[] sc = new saveContent[objName.Count];`
.
.

`string json = JsonHelper.ToJson(sc,true);`


I would like to create a button now that will allow the user to download the created Json file. 
I am totally beginner to Unity and C#, so learning things by doing :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice [File browser plugin](https://github.com/gkngkc/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser) that basically allowing me to do more or less everything that I was looking for. :) The Github repo also got a nice documentation!

Comment: Note that the linked plugin is mainly for standalone (windows/Linux/Mac) and explicitly states for WebGL `Not well tested, probably not much reliable.`